# Unity Error "Visual Studio Tools: failed to convert debug symbols, no pdb2mdb"

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, mono, managed

**TL; DR**

Why would Unity think there is no pdb2mdb when using Visual Studio Tools for Unity (VSTU)?

**Background**

I import my Unity scripts as [managed plugins](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingDLL.html) (DLLS) from Visual Studio.  That is, when I build my code in VS, I export the generated .dll and .pdb file to Unity, and the Visual Studio Tools for Unity (VSTU) extension handles converting the .pdb's to .mdb's so I can debug.  Recently however, when I build my DLLs in VS and export them to Unity, the Unity console displays the following error:

> Visual Studio Tools: failed to convert debug symbols, no pdb2mdb

pdb2mdb is the program within VSTU that converts .pdb to .mdb, and I have no idea why its supposedly missing all of a sudden.  I've tried cleaning/rebuilding my VS solution, restarting VS and Unity, and repairing my VS installation, all without success.  Even stranger, this behavior is happening on *two different computers* (albeit with all the same relevant software versions), which makes me nervous that the issue is somehow specific to my project.  All the information that I've been able to find so far is several years old and has not helped.

My development environment:

- Windows 10
- Unity 2017.2.0f3
- Visual Studio 2017 15.5.0
- VSTU 3.5.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same thing happened to me after upgrading to Visual Studio 2017 15.5.0.
Unfortunately there is no easy way to downgrade Visual Studio, so the best thing would be to wait for a fix.

**EDIT:**

**Solution**: Downgrade your visual studio to 15.0.

1. Uninstall version 15.5.0 by running visual studio installer and uninstalling any Visual Studio product.
2. Using you Microsoft account, login to http://my.visualstudio.com.
3. Download the installation of Visual Studio 15.0 and install it. Don't forget to check Visual Studio Tools for Unity.
4. Test and verify the issue is solved.

**EDIT 2:**

Sorry that it comes in phases, it's because I kept investigating it.
Once you have Visual Studio 2017 15.0 installed (instructions above), you can now upgrade to 15.2 (which is much more stable), doing the following:

1. Download the manifest file for 15.2 ([here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=84639805684731258986)) and put in C:\VS2017.
2. Download Visual Studio Community installer ([here](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/)) and put in the same directory.
3. Open command line window (as Administrator), change directory to C:\VS2017, and type:

   `vs_community.exe --installChannelUri "file:///C:/VS2017/ChannelManifest.json" --channelUri "https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/channel"`
4. You can now upgrade to 15.2!

Comment: How did you fix it?

Comment: @Yaniv thanks for the reply.  Is the fix that we're waiting for just a new version of the VSTU extension?

Comment: @Rabadash8820 I believe so. Either that or some adaptation by unity, because the pdb2mdb files are there anyway, look in your C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0 directory

Comment: I just found this: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/installing-an-earlier-release-of-vs2017 . I will try it and let you know if it works for me

Comment: I have updated the answer with the solution, follow the instructions and you should be OK

Comment: Seems like a hell of a step backwards... 15.0 came out back in March.  But if this is the only current solution then I'll accept your answer.  With any luck, VSTU will have been updated in a week or two, or one of us will be back here with a better answer.

Comment: @Rabadash8820 Just found a better solution to get you to 15.2, enjoy!

Comment: I've been working with 15.2 for a week now, works great with Unity, no issues.

Comment: @YanivShaked Alright, VS 15.5.3 is out now and an MS employee has stated on that other thread that pdb2mdb is working again.  I can confirm this as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Same problem with Visual Studio Enterprise 2017, version 15.5.1, which is the latest version at the time.

**EDIT 1:**

See this thread from MS Developer Community:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/164949/visual-studio-tools-for-unity-failed-to-convert-de.html

It seems that the issue has been already reported to MS and that they working on a fix. Meanwhile you can try to reach them at vstusp@microsoft.com to get a build of the Tools for Unity that fixes this issue. Good Luck.

**EDIT 2:**

As [Rabadash8820](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3991688/rabadash8820) said in comments, MS already fixed the bug in version 15.5.3 that should be released soon. Today I updated my VS to version 15.5.2 and the problem persists as expected.

**EDIT 3:**

The issue has been fixed in version 15.5.3, as reported [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/164949/visual-studio-tools-for-unity-failed-to-convert-de.html). You can download it [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/).

Comment: 15.5.1 isn't working for me either.  Thanks for linking that Developer Community link though, I'm glad to know that they're working on it.

Comment: Just got a response from an MS employee at that thread.  Looks like the fix will be coming out in 15.5.3

Comment: Yes, I've read your post and the reply on Developer Community. Hope that ver 15.5.3 comes out as soon as possible...

Answer (score 0):

Issue can be resolved by Upgrading the Mono Version. I have upgraded from 4.8 to 6.0.344.